# Thymeleaf form data integration with Spring Boot model attributes

Tags: spring-boot, forms, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have one simple thymeleaf page for user registraion. I have one entity to store the form data to hibernate . here is the thymeleaf page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Customer Registration</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <section>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <p>Sign up</p>

                        <form th:action="@{/register}" method="post" th:object="${employee}">

                            <div>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" name="firstName" required placeholder="First Name">
                            </div>

                            <div>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="LastName" name="lastName" required placeholder="Last Name">
                            </div>

                            <div>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" required placeholder="Email">
                            </div>

                            <div>
                                <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber" required placeholder="Mobile">
                            </div>

                            <div>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" required placeholder="Password">
                            </div>

                            <div>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword" required placeholder="Confirm Password">
                            </div>

                            <div>
                                <label>Role:</label>
                                <input type="radio" th:field="*{email}" th:value="admin" /> Admin
                                <input type="radio" th:field="*{email}" th:value="employee" /> Employee
                            </div>

                            <div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Register</button>
                            </div>

                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/new-templates/bootstrap-registration/draw1.webp"
                             class="img-fluid" alt="Sample image">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/309181c27b.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

In most of the blogs i am seeing they are using th:field="*{field name}". But in my case i did not use it , instead i used name attribute matching the field name from the entity class. My question is how it is working?

Entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "employee_id")
    private Long employeeId;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
```

I want to know how data is binding even though i am not following the syntax.

Comment: The databinding works as it uses request parameters. Parameters with name `x` are bound to the object to the property named `x`. (Where `x` can be any name ofcourse). Your form "works" but only for 1 way binding. It will bind the entered values to the object on the java side, but not the other way around. If you have a pre-filled `Employee` object and want to view the values on the form you need the `th:field` syntax for 2-way binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`th:field` sets the `name`, `value`, and `id` of the field.  Effectively, you are doing part the work of `th:field` by manually setting the `id` and `name` on your fields.

As for how it works, Spring is just matching up the field `name`s to the properties on the `@ModelAttribute` -- it doesn't care if the `name` of the field is set by Thymeleaf or a regular HTML attribute.